# How can I view Hebrew characters on my English Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I need to view a text file that contains Hebrew characters, how can I do this on Windows 7? I don't want to change my default language to Hebrew just view the file.

Comment: you really should state what problem you have when you try to view it.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the text file which contains the Hebrew characters?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the application more than Windows. Viewing Hebrew (or most any non-English language) will generally require Unicode support from the application in question. For example, if I copy a bunch of Hebrew characters from Charmap, and paste them into Word, they show up fine. If however I paste them into KEDIT, they show up as just question marks. This is the difference between Unicode and Non-Unicode -supporting applications. Some applications, instead of question marks, will show just little boxes for each Unicode character.

Windows Media Player for example only recently added Unicode support... a version or two ago music I had with Unicode names (Hebrew and Russian) all just showed up as unknown characters.

You would need to find out whether the application you are trying to use supports Unicode, or plans to. Otherwise you would need to find a different application to use if you want Unicode support. What program are you using to try to view the file?

Comment: Also, not all fonts have the Unicode characters present in them for use. What font are you using in said program?

Comment: I think, in notepad anyway.. win xp.. if not using a font with hebrew chars, then you get squares(as oppose to say question marks).. The fonts "Miriam", and "David", are standard and support hebrew.  Another one not standard,  this one not standard, is SBL Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to view the text? If you have the language fonts installed on the machine you should be able to view it. Otherwise, goto
Control Panel->type "Regional"
Click on Regional and Language Options and install the necessary language if not already installed.
Now you should be able to view the text in Hebrew.
Your default language will still be English.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to install the language packs. I do not have any additional language packs installed on my Win7, and yet I am able to see and use both Russian and Hebrew characters (among others) just fine.